# Handling Sinumerik Alarms with Event Based MonitoredItem on a .Net Core OPC UA client

Tags: .net-core, event-handling, opc-ua, opc, siemens

I'm trying to monitor alarm events on a OPC UA client utilizing event based monitored items. I subscribe to the node: `ns=2;s=Sinumerik` and add the corresponding attributes and filters. Later on I handle the notification on a OnNotification() method as shown in the code below.

```
var list = new List<MonitoredItem> { new MonitoredItem(_subscription.DefaultItem) {StartNodeId = "ns=2;s=Sinumerik" } };

foreach (MonitoredItem item in list)
{
    item.AttributeId = Attributes.EventNotifier;
    item.MonitoringMode = MonitoringMode.Reporting;
    item.SamplingInterval = -1;
    item.QueueSize = 100;
    item.DiscardOldest = false;
    EventFilter filter = new EventFilter();
    filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType, Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.Message);
    filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType, Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.Severity);
    item.Filter = filter;
    item.Notification += OnNotification;
}

_subscriptions[subscriptionNum].Create();
_subscriptions[subscriptionNum].ApplyChanges();
```

The OnNotification() method looks like this:

```
private void OnNotification(MonitoredItem item, MonitoredItemNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var value in item.DequeueValues())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Display Name: " + item.DisplayName + "Value: " + value.Value);
    }
}
```

I receive the event notification but there are no Values in the MonitoredItem.

Is this the correct way to monitor event based monitored items for Sinumerik Alarms using OPC UA?

Comment: I have nearly the same problem, how do you solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing for Events, not other data attributes, so try `item.DequeueEvents()` instead.

Comment: `item.DequeueEvents()` returns no values. I see that some of the information I need is being stored in the  `MonitoredItemNotificationEventArgs e` variable but I'm not able to access it in runtime, only while debugging